# python deleting number values except letters

Tags: python, dictionary

how can I delete all numbers in dict values?

```
{
    "1": [
        "Date 1 Food.",
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date 2 Food",
    ],
}
```

to

```
    "1": [
        "Date Food.",
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date Food",
    ],
}
```

I used .find and for& in but didn't works well..

Comment: Please add your code to question, so that we can help you correct your code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a way to get at the strings so you can substitute out the numbers. The simple way is to loop over the items and then replace the lists with lists of strings that have been processed:

```
import re 

d = {
    "1": [
        "Date 1 Food.",
        "Date 1      Fo2334 od.",
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date 2 Food",
    ],
}

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [re.sub(r'\d+\W*', '', s) for s in v]
    
print(d)
# {'1': ['Date Food.', 'Date Food.'], '2': ['Date Food']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will update your dictionary by removing the digits from string

```
import re

dictionary_variable = {
    "1": [
        "Date 1 Food.",
    ],
    "2": [
        "Date 2 Food",
    ],
}

def replace_digit(s):
    return re.sub('\d', '', s)

def remove_num_from_dict(dictionary_variable):
    return {k: replace_digit(v[0]) for k, v in dictionary_variable.items()}
    
updated_dictionary = remove_num_from_dict(dictionary_variable)
print(updated_dictionary)
```